# How to build plugins having different versions from a single parent pom.xml?

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho

I am trying to build several Eclipse plug-ins with Maven Tycho. All the plug-ins does not have the same version number.

Let's say the following pom architecture:

- plugin1 (version 1.0.6.qualifier) / pom.xml
- plugin2 (version 1.4.0.qualifier) / pom.xml
- pom.xml (parent pom version 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT)

Maven's build fails with the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-plugin:0.12.0:validate-version (default-validate-version) on project plugin1: Unqualified OSGi version 1.0.6.qualifier must match unqualified Maven version 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT for SNAPSHOT builds
```

How to configure the parent pom to be able to build those plug-ins with different version numbers?
Should I use a different pom architecture to solve this issue?

Note that I don't want to modify plug-in's versions.

Comment: The error message shows that you have a completely different problem than what you describe. This problem is *not* that the plug-ins have different version. So this question isn't useful to others and should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I added a version tag corresponding to the Eclipse plug-in version in each modules' pom.xml.

Is it possible to use maven pom.xml files without any version tag and let tycho using version specified in MANIFEST.MF files?

Comment: This is not the place to ask new questions - open a new question instead.

Answer (score 11):

maven POM version and MANIFEST version must match (with suffix ".qualifer" in MANIFEST replaced by "-SNAPSHOT" in pom.xml).

See http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Packaging_Types#eclipse-plugin

Answer (score 2):

You can configure tycho plugin like that in order to only Warn versions problems : http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-packaging-plugin/validate-version-mojo.html

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-packaging-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <strictVersions>false</strictVersions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Result :

```
[INFO] --- tycho-packaging-plugin:0.16.0:validate-version (default-validate-version) @ org.apache.commons.io ---
[WARNING] Unqualified OSGi version 5.1.0.qualifier must match unqualified Maven version 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT for SNAPSHOT builds
```

Answer (score 1):

Even i have faced the same problem and found the solution for the same.

Actually the problem is Manifest.MF file version and pom.xml parent version should be same otherwise we will get this error.

Manifest.MF
Bundle-Version: 2.5.0.qualifier

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.example.pma</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.example.pma.product.parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../com.example.pma.product.parent</relativePath>
</parent>
```